# Random effects for within subjects study in R

Tags: r, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I have data which consists of subjective ratings.  The ratings are done by different judges with each subject being judged under different experimental conditions.  Each subject undergoes each condition and every judge (i.e. for two judges and three conditions there are six ratings per subject).

I am interested in the effect of the specific conditions, but not the effect of the specific judges whom I consider as drawn from a large population of possible judges.  That makes the condition a fixed factor and the judges a random factor.

1) I believe that both the condition and the judge are within-subjects factors because each subject is exposed to each combination of condition and judge.  However, I am unsure because the same judges and same conditions are used for all subjects.

2) Which R function is best for this kind of data, and how would I specify the model?  For example, I tried ezANOVA, but could not find how to specify the judges as a random factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for package `lme4`.

If I understand correctly, `mF` below should be your model. It has `condition` as a **fixed effect**, while `judge` and `subject` as a **random intercepts**.

```
library(lme4)

# m0 = Null model without the fixed effects.
# m1 = Your model including the fixed effects.
# Set REML = FALSE for a meaningful model comparison

m0 <- lmer(rating ~ 1 + (1|judge) + (1|subject), data = data, REML = FALSE) 
mF <- lmer(rating ~ condition + (1|judge) + (1|subject), data = data, REML = FALSE) 

summary(m0)
summary(mF)

anova(m0, mF)

# If significant, fit the final model using REML = TRUE
# This is often recommended since it usually gives better estimates for random effects.

mF <- lmer(rating ~ condition + (1|judge) + (1|subject), data = data, REML = FALSE)
```

**Edit:** Per discussion below.

Comment: Why do you advocate for `REML=FALSE`..? REML is generally a good default.

Comment: It is my understanding that REML isn't a meaningful way to compare models that differ in their fixed effects. The advice I've seen usually is to use ML for comparisons and REML for the final (best) model.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  I also added a (1|subjects) term since it is all within-subjects.  It seems to work correctly.

Comment: @foto51 ok, however it would be better if you included this description in your answer since we don't know if OP is already familiar with LMM's, and so not to give him or her impression that `REML=FALSE` is a good "default" approach.

Comment: Thanks again.  I only have previous experience with LM's and not LMM's so the discussion about REML is helpful.  FYI, if you use REML and try to do a model comparison with anova then it generates the message `refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)`.  This seems to support the discussion here.

Comment: The point in that during `REML` one transform the response variable. The original model $y = X\beta + Z\gamma + \epsilon$ is multiplied by a matrix $K$ such that $KX = 0$; as a result you are fitting $Ky = K(Z\gamma + \epsilon)$. Clearly comparing the fit of two models having different response variables is nonsensical (as $K$ depends on $X$ and different fixed effects dictate different $X$ matrices). ie. Use `ML` for model comparison. :) (In fairness you won't usually get *drastically* different results if you use `REML`).